# What is the Runtime of this recursive algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity, asymptotics, recurrence-relation

I am learning algorithm complexities. So far it has been an interesting ride. There is so much going behind the scenes that I need to understand. I find it difficult to understand complexity in recursive function.

`my_func` takes an array parameter `A` of length $n$. Runtime of `some_func()` is constant.

```python
def my_func(A): 
  if (n < 4):
    some_func(); /* O(1) time */
  else:
    [G1, G2, G3, G4] = split(A) /* split A into 4 disjoint subarrays of size n/4 each */
    my_func([G1, G3]); /* recurses on size n/2 */
   my_func([G1, G4]); /* recurses on size n/2 */
   my_func([G2, G3]); /* recurses on size n/2 */
   my_func([G2, G4]); /* recurses on size n/2 */
   some_other_func(); /* split() and some_other_func() take O(n) time */
```

**Questions**

1. Can I say the asymptotic runtime of `my_func` is
   $$T(n) = 4T(n/2) + O(n) \text{ with } T(1) = O(1)$$because `my_func` is called recursively $4$ times for $(n/2)$ size, then split is $O(n)$ and `some_other_func` is $O(n)$. The base case keeps $T(1) = O(1)$
2. What is the total number of steps performed by `my_func(A)`?
   I know that if there are nested for loops then simply multiply. How to calculate in this case? I was trying use Google search and it point to $\Omega(n^3)$. Is that correct?

Now what if I rewrite this function as

```python
def new_func(A): /* A is array of length n 8/
  if (n < 4):
    some_func(); /* O(1) time */
  else:
   [G1, G2, G3, G4] = split(A) /* split A into 4 disjoint subarrays of size n/4 each 
   new_func([G1, G2]); /* recurses on size n/2  */
   new_func([G2, G3]); /* recurses on size n/2  */
   new_func([G3, G4]); /* recurses on size n/2  */
   some_other_func(); /* split() and some_other_func() take O(n) time */
```

**Questions**

1. What is the number of steps now?
   I guess it will be $\Omega(n^3)$
2. Is `new_func` faster than $n\log(n)?$
   I think no because Merge sort is $T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n$ and `new_func` is $T(n) = nT(n/2) + n$

Comment: There's something mixed up in ur writing, the 2nd with *new_func()* doesn't differ than above except for the recursive call is 3times (not 2 as u wrote in Q). In general, u could substitute*T(n)= aT(n/b)+cn* =⟩ *T(n)=a[aT(n/b²)+c(n/b)]+cn*, then work ur way out to *logn to base b* times (when u reach T(1) as n is divided to b^(logn base b) which equals n). Take care in here a=b², so a^(log n base b) = n²

Answer (score 1):

In `my_func(a)`, **Recurrence Relation** will be

$T(n) =
  \begin{cases}
    4T\bigg(\frac{n}{2}\bigg)+{n} & \quad \text{if } n \geq 4\\   
    1  & \quad \text{if } n <4
  \end{cases}
$

In `new_func(a)`, **Recurrence Relation** will be

$T(n) =
  \begin{cases}
    3T\bigg(\frac{n}{2}\bigg)+{n} & \quad \text{if } n \geq 4\\   
    1  & \quad \text{if } n <4
  \end{cases}
$

You can solve Both of these **Recurrence Relations** using [**Master Theorem**](https://ediscretestructures.blogspot.com/2022/03/master-theorem-for-recurrence-relation.html) as explained in link.

The **Time Complexity** of `my_func(a)` will be $\theta(n^2)$ since $\log_24 = 2$

The **Time Complexity** of `new_func(a)` will be $\theta(n^{1.5849})$ since $\log_23 = 1.5849$

You can solve both of these questions by **Substitution Method**, which is Time Consuming. One of the [Example](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/143992/143377) using this method is attached.

The `new_func(a)` will be slower than `Merge Sort`, and faster than `my_func(a)`.